# Splitting an alphanumeric character to sort and then concatenating back in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort a bunch of alphanumeric characters that look like this:

```
[AD850X, MP342X, OP452X, ZC234X, ZC540X]
```

The sorting should be based off only numbers, so I have to remove all alpha characters from this code and then I want to add those characters back after I sort them for the purposes of my code as they were before. For example, the above string should first look like this:

```
[850, 342, 452, 234, 540]
```

Then this,

```
[234, 342, 452, 540, 850]
```

And then finally this,

```
[ZC234X, MP342X, OP452X, ZC540X, AD850X]
```

I've been thinking about how to do this and I'm not sure how I would get the same two letters in the front to reattach to the numeric code after sorting (the last character, in this case "X,"would always be the same and I would concatenate this value after adding the first two alpha characters as they were before.

If anyone could help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

EDIT: One other question, once this runs, I want to only output the low and high value of the array (which can have different number of elements). I tried using .min and .max but not sure how to do that with the array that logs after you sort. So in the case above I would just need "ZC234X" and "AD850X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of complicating it by removing the two first letters and then sorting, you could just sort the array comparing only the matched numbers inside each element.

```js
var arr = ['AD850X', 'MP342X', 'OP452X', 'ZC234X', 'ZC540X'],
    res = arr.sort((a,b) => a.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.match(/\d+/)[0]),
    min = res[0],
    max = res[res.length-1];
 
    console.log("min value: " + min + " | max value: " + max);
```

Comment: Edit: One other question, once this runs, I want to only output the low and high value of the array (which can have different number of elements). I tried using .min and .max but not sure how to do that with the array that logs after you sort. So in the case above I would just need "ZC234X" and "AD850X".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2):

You can use object as hash table to store element and its number and then sort by values form that object.

```js
var data = ['AD850X', 'MP342X', 'OP452X', 'ZC234X', 'ZC540X'];
var obj = {}

data.forEach(e => obj[e] = e.match(/\d+/)[0])
var result = data.sort((a, b) => obj[a] - obj[b]);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Nina Scholz No problem `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use just the matched nummerical values for sorting. [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works in situ.

This proposal uses a default value, if the regular expression does not match a number.

```js
var array = ['AD850X', 'MP342X', 'OP452X', 'ZC234X', 'ZC540X'];

array.sort((a, b) => (a.match(/\d+/) || 0) - (b.match(/\d+/) || 0));

console.log('min value', array[0]);
console.log('max value', array[array.length - 1]);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```